# What are some efficient data structures in python to store and process large dataset?

Tags: python, data-structures

I am trying to create a data loader for an OCR system. I have 1k document images in which each document contains roughly 200 lines of text. Presently I am extracting each line image along with its ground truth and then append them to a list. I was wondering if there are any efficient data structure where I can quickly store and retrive data  without hogging too much memory.

```
    class OCRDataset(tud.Dataset):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            self.config = kwargs['config']
            self.dir = self.config['dir']
            self.books = self.config["books"]
        def __len__(self):
            return len(self.books)
        def __getitem__(self, idx):
            pagewise = read_book(book_path=os.path.join(self.dir, self.books[idx]))
            sequences, targets = pagewise
            samples = [(sequences[i], targets[i]) for i in range(len(sequences))]
            return samples

    total = []
    dataset = OCRdataset(config=config)
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        sample = dataset[i]
        total.extend(sample)
```

As you can see the `class OCRdataset` takes a book and returns a list of tuples containing images and annotations. I have several such books and I iterate through each book using a for loop and then extend the list `total` after every iteration. The bottle neck is that after extending the list for first few books my system eventually starts to slow down. I would be grateful if anybody can suggest a better way of doing this. 
Thank You

**EDIT**: The idea behind using the `total` list is  to load data from multiple books into a single data structure which will then allow me to split the data into training and validation set and then subsequently use it for traing my classifier.

**EDIT 2**: The function `read_book` takes a collection of document images and returns the list of tuples containg line images along with their annotations for a particular book.

Comment: Are you concerned about _space_ ("without hogging too much memory") or _speed_ ("this will slow down my system")? It is not clear what you are trying to optimize.

Comment: I am worried that if I take too much RAM it will slow down my system?

Comment: Speed and space are two different and in general unrelated dimensions.

Comment: Hello, @Dyz I may be completely wrong but if a DS utilises too much RAM, won't it affect the performance of my code?

Comment: No, unless it does not _fit_ into the RAM.

Comment: Thanks @DyZ for pointing this out but in my past experiences whenever I have worked with huge lists or dictionaries my system kind of slows down, can you tell me what might be the reason behind this so that I can optimize my code accordingly.

Comment: You never explained what is purpose of building the `total` list. It is not possible to optimize a data structure if its purpose is unclear.

Comment: @DyZ I updated my question and explained the purpose of building the `total` list. Please have look.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest writing it directly to output line by line instead of keeping one huge object in your memory.

```
file=open("outputfile.txt")
dataset = OCRdataset(config=config)
for i in range(len(dataset)):
   sample = dataset[i]
   file.write(sample)
file.close()
```

For retrieving data I suggest using pandas since it allows using iterators (have a look at the chunksize option of the DataFrame.read_csv() function)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Dzurico